# Android lock screen when phone is rebooted

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an Android lock screen app and I completed all features except one.

When the phone has rebooted, it shows the home screen, but I want to show my lock screen app so I added the following broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="receiver.LockScreenReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and in the `onreceive()` method, I start an activity. When the phone has rebooted, my lock screen app opens after 5-10 seconds later, but I want to show my app when the phone has rebooted.

I cannot find any solution. I saw many lock screen apps and they opens with a maximum of 5-10 seconds delay.

I found an app - [Next lock screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.next&hl=en). It works. It opens the first time after rebooting the phone.

Comment: The receiver is fine but where is the implementation for that receiver?

Comment: @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
    || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
    || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
   start_lockscreen(context);
  }
 }

 // Display lock screen
 private void start_lockscreen(Context context) {
  Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
  mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(mIntent);
 }

Answer (score 0):

This can increase you priority but still there would be some delay. Since android first load its OS and the all the other activity starts.

```
<receiver
    android:name="receiver.LockScreenReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: According to android document priority range is 0-999